# React Native - Fetch Problem: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem. I call/request url in this code;

```
fetch("http://url",{
method:'GET',
headers: {
Accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
})
.then(res=>
console.log(res)
)
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

But i get the error:
**TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**
And i am checking console network then i see **CORS failed.**

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: So this is a CORS error and there are hundreds maybe thousands of questions answered in StackOverflow regarding CORS errors. Make sure you are calling GET on correct url/endpoint and check answered CORS related questions

Comment: I fixed. I post answred. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. If I call/request with an android device, it's not a problem.
But if I call/request with the web, that's time get the error.
That's why I am not using a web interface.

An edit of my code:

```
fetch("http://url",{
          method:'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(res=>{
          console.log("ImageUrl: ", res);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```